# Call Class inside unittest class Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have python class script to get file in google storage bucket, create datasets,tables and load it to bigquery.

Well, When I test this class, it works for fews methods. The test class doesn't keep variables when I run other method of FileToBq class. When I use FileToBq class alone, it works.

I have the following error:

- AttributeError: 'FileToBq' object has no attribute 'datasetname'*

```
class TestMyClass(unittest.TestCase):
    uri = call_test_file()
    tobq = FileToBq(uri, region, GCP_PROJECT)

    def test_parse_file(self):
        # call parse method 
        table_id = self.tobq.parse_file()
        self.assertRegex(table_id, '[a-zA-Z_-]+.[a-zA-Z_-]+.tbl_[a-zA-Z_-]+')

    ...
            
    def test_create_table(self):
        result : self.tobq.create_table()
        self.assertIn(result, {'table_created', 'table_exists'}) 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

```
class FileToBq:
    def __init__(self, blob_object, region, GCP_PROJECT):
        self.blob_object = blob_object
        self.region = region
        self.bucketname = str(blob_object.bucket.name)
        self.filename = str(blob_object.name)
        self.timeCreated = blob_object.time_created  
        self.GCP_PROJECT = GCP_PROJECT
        self.job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
    
    def parse_file(self):
        #Parse filename
        self.date, self.datasetname, self.tablename = self.filename.replace('.csv', '').split(';')
        self.table_id = '%s.%s.tbl_%s' % (self.GCP_PROJECT, self.datasetname, self.tablename)
        return self.table_id

    def create_table(self):
        ...
        self.dataset = bigquery.Dataset(self.datasetname)
...
```

Comment: In FileToBq \_\_init__ method, why don't you add a default value for *datasetname*, such as `self.datasetname = ""`?

Comment: Thanks, Because I don't know datasetname. I get the last file in my bucket. I have multiple methods in my Class which get some dynamic variables (tableId, json data ...). If I do that, I have to put all my code in the init part.

Comment: Is it failing when testing the create_table method or when testing test_parse_file?
Would you be able to provide a stacktrace? This would be helpful to locate where the issue might be. 
If your FileToBq class works, it looks like that your issue is in your unit test and probably not related bigquery's client library.